# Bangla Complex Font problem in system Tray

Tags: fonts, date

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

On my system tray on upper top right corner where the date is located, the date is showing শুক্ র instead of শুক্র. And time as 11:23:27 অপরাণ্ হ instead of অপরাহ্ন. So, complex words are showing separated.

I ran

```
fc-match -a | grep -i beng
```

Output came:

```
Lohit-Bengali.ttf: "Lohit Bengali" "Regular"
```

Comment: Please run the command `fc-match -a | grep -i beng` and let us know the output by editing your question.

Comment: Lohit-Bengali.ttf: "Lohit Bengali" "Regular"

Comment: Ok. I posted an answer with an idea. Please try it and let us know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can raise the precedence of the Lohit Bengali font by adding this configuration file:

```
$ cat ~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-bangla-preferred.conf
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <alias>
        <family>sans-serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Lohit Bengali</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

Steps:

- Create the directory:

  ```
  mkdir -p ~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d
  ```
- Open the new document for editing:

  ```
  gedit ~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-bangla-preferred.conf
  ```
- Copy the above (as from "`<?xml version="1.0"?>`") and paste it into the document.
- Save.

Hopefully it will result in a difference after next reboot.

Comment: I can't do it.. how to do this ? Please detail..

Comment: @user642711: I edited my answer.

Comment: Sir I tried both the steps. Rebooted but all this is as previous. System Tray still showing অপরাহ্ ণ instead of অপরাহ্ন..

Comment: @user642711: Please run: `LC_TIME=bn_BD date +'%A %B'` to check if the problem is present in the terminal too.

Comment: Yes this exist. Complex words not showing correctly. Showing রব িব ার জ া ন ু য় া র ি instead of রবিবার জানুয়ারি. But if I copy and paste to Libre office from terminal then this show correctly.

Comment: @user642711: This appears to be a bug (in both Unity and gnome-terminal), and it's over my head to figure out how to deal with it. I googled and found [this page](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unicode-font-rendering-broken-with-devanagari-fonts.251788/), for instance.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help.. Peace be upon you.May Allah bless you..And again thanks..